# Создание xsl:element с помощью xsl:element

Tags: xml, парсер, xls, xslt

Есть схема, которая может изменяться.
Даётся файл xml, не полностью удовлетворяющий этой схеме. Т.е. в нем могут отсутствовать некоторые узлы, прописанные в схеме.
Надо преобразовать с помощью xslt данный файл так, чтобы на месте отсутствующих узлов появились пустые.
Чтобы один раз решить задачу, решил написать xslt, который по схеме создаёт другой xslt, в котором вызывется метод выводя для каждого узла. Если узел найден, выводятся его параметры, иначе пустой узел.
Все бы ничего, только во втором xslt нужно использовать `xsl:element`, а чтобы его получить, надо использовать `<xls:element>` в первом xslt)))

Может я чего-то не знаю, но стандартный способ создания `xsl:element` я не нашел (застопорился на создании контента нового `xsl:element`).
Пробовал через `<xls:value-of>`, тоже почти получилось, но упорно не желают выводиться `>` и `<`.
Может кто-нибудь знает как:

1. Либо через `xsl:element` создать `xsl:element`
2. Либо вывести `>` и `<`.

Comment: А использовать условие вам нельзя?

    <xsl:if test="//rootnode/subnode/@attr"><!-- body --></xsl:if>

или

    <xsl:choose>
       <!-- Content:(xsl:when+,xsl:otherwise?) -->
    </xsl:choose>

Comment: можно, даже скорее нужно, только как мне это поможет в создании xsl:element, либо избавит от его создания? схема может меняться и в первом xslt я не знаю какие узлы прописаны в схеме

Comment: А как вы тогда составляете XSL, если вы узлов не знаете?

Comment: @Dex, Я их беру из схемы, в вопросе это написано

Answer (score 1):

Пример создания `xsl:element` с помощью `xsl:element`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
            <xsl:attribute name="match">/</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="rootelementofresultdoc">Некий элемент некого документа</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Угловые скобки выводятся с помощью предопределённых сущностей `&lt; и &gt;`:

```
<xsl:template name="ltgt">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;xsl:apply-templates /&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ваш пример создает xslt, внутри его xsl:template, а внутри узел <rootelementofresultdoc>, но xsl:element так и не создался
Я уже сам разобрался, извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, надо было например так:
        <xsl:element name="xsl:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'xsl:template'"/>
        </xsl:element>
За подсказку с угловыми скобками спасибо